# Why does maxClauseCount exceeded depends on the number of nested documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, opensearch

Using ElasticSearch (7.10) or OpenSearch (1.3) I get an error "maxClauseCount exceeded" when I query an index that contain nested documents, but it only fails if the number of nested documents exceed some unknown threshold. The error is:

```
runtime_exception: [turns.messages:wo* ] exceeds maxClauseCount [ Boolean maxClauseCount is set to 2048]
```

So, I could query my `my-index_2023-01` with no problem and get the results I expect, but if I use the same query with `my-index_2023-02` it fails. The only difference seems to be that the latter contains one or more documents with "too many" nested objects.

The field I am trying to query is on the nested document, a document may contain many nested "messages". Here is a subsection of the query I am attempting to execute:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "filter": [{
        "nested": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": [{
                        "span_near": {
                            "clauses": [{
                                    "span_term": {
                                        "message.text": {
                                            "value": "hello",
                                            "boost": 1.0
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "span_multi": {
                                        "match": {
                                            "wildcard": {
                                                "messages.text": {
                                                    "wildcard": "wo*",
                                                    "boost": 1.0
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "boost": 1.0
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "slop": 0,
                            "in_order": true,
                            "boost": 1.0,
                            "_name": "phrase: hello wo*"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }]
  }
}
```

Why does the query fail on those indices with documents with "too many" nested objects?
Why does the number of nested objects on a single document of the index affects whether the query can be executed or not?